# How to add a <br> after a div that contains a specific value for an attribute with JSoup

Tags: java, html, dom, tags, jsoup

I have the following `html`:

```
<div type= "HEADER"> hello there </div>
```

I want to insert a `<br></br>` after it.

This is what I've tried so far but unfortunately it is not working:

```
Document doc = Jsoup.parse("<div type= \"HEADER\"> hello there </div>");
doc.select("[type=*HEADER]").after("<br></br>");
```

so, what do you suggest ?

Comment: *"how to add a <br> after a div attribute..."* It's an element, not an attribute.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two things:

1. If you wanted `type=HEADER` divs, that would be `div[type=HEADER]`. If you wanted any `div` with `HEADER` *anywhere* in the `type` attribute, that would be `*=` (not `=*`).
2. [`br`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/text-level-semantics.html#the-br-element) is a [void element](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#void-elements), it never has an opening and closing tag.

So:

```
doc.select("div[type=HEADER]").after("<br>");    // Exact match
doc.select("div[type*=HEADER]").after("<br>");   // Contains
```

...or

```
doc.select("div[type=HEADER]").after("<br/>");   // Exact match
doc.select("div[type*=HEADER]").after("<br/>");  // Contains
```

...if you want go do the XHTML thing.

Comment: the "div" after "[type=HEADER]" is the key.

Answer (score 4):

Your selector is wrong. You have:

```
doc.select("[type=*HEADER]")
```

but it should be:

```
doc.select("[type*=HEADER]")
```

See the [selector documentation.](http://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/selector-syntax)